# How to make the floor completely white and with shadows

Tags: three.js

Please help me make the floor completely white and with shadows, as in the drawing. I tried different materials, emissive color, turn on and off the map of the scene environment and light sources, still my plane is gray, not white.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLMx3.png)

Comment: Can you just use the code from this official `three.js` example? https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending

Comment: I assume you made sure your light and floor we’re both white (#ffffff), but could we see some code to check?

Comment: I use Lambert material for the floor, the lighting and floor color is white. I also use ACESFilmicToneMapping for rendering, without it the shadows disappear.